# Как необходимо изменить код так, чтобы можно было вводить несколько sourcePrefix?

Tags: java

Есть файл s1, который нужно скопировать в s. Но как сделать так, чтобы можно было несколько файлов скопировать в один и как реализовать с помощью try-with-resourse?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Task2 {
    public Task2() {
    }

    static void unsplit (String sourcePrefix, String destination){
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(sourcePrefix);
            os = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        unsplit(
                "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s1.txt",
                "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s.txt"
        );
    }
}
```

Я попытался это сделать, но оно не хочет добавлять в public static void main новые sourcePrefix.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Task2 {
    public Task2() {
    }

    static void unsplit (String sourcePrefix, String destination){
        try {
            FileInputStream is_1 = new FileInputStream(sourcePrefix);
            FileInputStream is_2 = new FileInputStream(sourcePrefix);
            FileInputStream is_3 = new FileInputStream(sourcePrefix);
            FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            SequenceInputStream sis=new SequenceInputStream(is_1,is_2,is_3);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = sis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            sis.close();
            is_1.close();
            is_2.close();
            is_3.close();
            os.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        unsplit(
                "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s1.txt",
                "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s.txt"
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

?

```
static void unsplit(String destination, String... sourcePrefix) {
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destination)) {
        for (String src : sourcePrefix) {
            try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(src)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    unsplit(
            "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s.txt",
            "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s1.txt",
            "E:\\Java\\14 лабораторная\\src\\com\\example\\Lab14\\s2.txt"
    );
}
```

Сигнатура метода `static void unsplit (String sourcePrefix, String destination)` у вас не поменялась. И дополнительные аргументы добавлять некуда.

Для нескольких однотипных аргументов используется запись `method(Class... args){}`. Внутри метода переменная `args` будет массивом `Class[]` и содержать в массиве все аргументы, которые вы ввели. Обращаться к ним можно по индексу `args[index]` или с помощью итератора, как в коде выше.

Comment: Оно не копирует информацию из s1 и s2 в s

Comment: У меня есть три файла: s1, s2 и s3. И мне надо скопировать весь текст из них в txt файл s.

Comment: Поменяйте аргументы местами. Сначала s, потом s1, s2, s3.

Comment: Я так сделал. Но он мне скопировать текст из s2 и s3 в s1 и раза 4-5 одно и тоже. А s остался пустым.

Comment: Хотя даже не так. Он скопировал текст из s2 и s3 в s, но несколько раз, а текст из s1 не скопировал в s.

Comment: И еще такой вопрос, как здесь закрыть ресурсы?

Comment: Ресурсы закрываются автоматически после выхода из блока `try{}`. В этом смысл записи `try-with-resourse`.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я решил поменять содержимое s1, s2, s3. А в s все-равно появляется старый текст, еще и добавляется с каждым разом (то есть два предложения повторяются раза 4-5 и без содержимого s1). Как сделать нормально?

Comment: У меня данный код вполне корректно переписывает текст из исходных файлов в файл s. Возможно вы где-то держите файл открытым или какая то подобная причина.

Comment: Уже все хорошо. Я разобрался. Спасибо большое.